# 3D Touch Quick Actions really slow to launch (restarts the app instead of resuming?)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

I've tried my best to look for a similar question on this site and on Google, but I couldn't find anything. 
I have tried adding 3D Touch Quick Actions to my app, following one of the many tutorials found on the internet.
The problem is, everytime I perform the action from the home screen (testing on a 6S Plus), I see the LaunchScreen.storyboard screen and I have to wait a couple of seconds for the app to launch. This happens even if i just backgrounded the app. If I just tap the icon, I am instantly taken back to the last screen, but if I use the shortcut, it looks like the app restarts instead of resuming.

Is this the intended way of Quick Actions to work? Because it seems different to me with the Apple stock apps.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same problem. Not too sure if it's because it's a test build compiled from Xcode or something else...

Comment: Have the same issue here. Do you have a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately still waiting for an answer or some help...